# How to know where in a UITableViewCell a user tapped?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm writing a universal iOS app and in it I have a `UITableView` that is set to allow `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing`.  Just to refresh your memory, this means that each cell of the table has a small check box to the left of it.  When I'm in editing mode, is there a way I can determine if the user tapped the small checkbox or if they tapped the rest of the cell?  I want different methods to be called depending on if they tapped the box or the rest of the cell.  For instance,

```
if(user tapped checkbox)
{
    foo();
}
else if (user tapped any part of the cell other than checkbox)
{
    foobar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  Just add a gesture recognizer to each `UITableViewCell` and set the recognizer to call this method:

```
UITableViewCell *cellTapped = (UITableViewCell *) recognizer.view;
CGPoint tapLocationInContentView = [recognizer locationInView:cellTapped.contentView];
if(tapLocationInContentView.x < 0 )
{
    //Checkbox tapped
}
else 
{
    //Rest of cell tapped
}
```